# Maven build causes VerifyError with java 1.7

Tags: java, maven, junit, cobertura, verifyerror

I got one simple class with test case for it and everything works fine in eclipse, but when I run maven build (with this goals : install cobertura:cobertura checkstyle:checkstyle-aggregate) I'm seeing a Verify error in surefire report.

Here is the exact error :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.diploma.testProject.ClassUnderTestTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.034 sec <<< FAILURE!
testMethodReturnsTrue(com.diploma.testProject.ClassUnderTestTest)  Time elapsed: 0.005 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 79 in method com.diploma.testProject.ClassUnderTest.method(II)Z at offset 24
    at com.diploma.testProject.ClassUnderTestTest.testMethodReturnsTrue(ClassUnderTestTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)

testMethodReturnFalse(com.diploma.testProject.ClassUnderTestTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 79 in method com.diploma.testProject.ClassUnderTest.method(II)Z at offset 24
    at com.diploma.testProject.ClassUnderTestTest.testMethodReturnFalse(ClassUnderTestTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

This is the class :

```
public class ClassUnderTest {
    public static boolean method(int a, int b) {
        if ( a == b) {
            System.out.println("");
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the test :

```
public class ClassUnderTestTest {

    @Test
    public void testMethodReturnsTrue() {
        assertTrue(ClassUnderTest.method(1, 1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodReturnFalse() throws Exception {
        assertFalse(ClassUnderTest.method(1, 2));
    }

}
```

And pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.diploma</groupId>
  <artifactId>testProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>testProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <testSource>1.7</testSource>
                    <testTarget>1.7</testTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

When setting the target to 1.5 this works but I need it to work with 1.7. 
More strange is that modifying the method to have only one return like this :

```
public class ClassUnderTest {
    public static boolean method(int a, int b) {
        if ( a == b) {
            System.out.println("");
        } 
        return false;
    }
}
```

also fixes the problem. 
I've tried setting the target and source version in properties block of pom, but the result was the same.

Is there a way to make this running on version 1.7?

EDIT : Also this problem appears only with goal cobertura:cobertura.

Comment: This seems to be a common problem, with very similar questions posted on SO. I posted the resolution to our problem was resolved with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20001391/1279002

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem seems to be in cobertura. Looks like it doesn't support java 1.7 very good. 
The fix was similar to the link that @Raghuram wrote for the eclipse. 
Modifying pom like this makes test works fine :

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <testSource>1.7</testSource>
                    <testTarget>1.7</testTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: A similar setting works with buildr:ENV['JAVA_OPTS'] ||= "-XX:UseSplitVerifier"

Answer (score 4):

Edit: `mvn cobertura:cobertura` does not work due to lack of support of cobertura for Java 7.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151470/cobertura-java-7-support) discusses this.  Looks like [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/index.html) is the way to go.

`mvn install` works fine for me from command-line with `maven-3.0.4` and `java 1.7.0_04` on Windows 7.  Possibly you are hitting [this eclipse bug](http://java.dzone.com/articles/javalangverifyerror-expecting)?

To add to @Pau' answer, `<pluginManagement>` is used in multi-module poms to declare `<plugin>` elements that can be inherited as required by children.

I get no errors with the `pom` in the question as well the following snippet:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <testSource>1.7</testSource>
                <testTarget>1.7</testTarget>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Hm.. I got the same error from command line too, but now I found out that its from the goal cobertura:cobertura. When running only install works fine. 
Thanks for the note about the <pluginManagement>

Comment: @ZhivkoDelchev. I get the same error with `cobertura`.  Updated the answer

Comment: Cobertura 2.x is new, claims java 7 support.

Comment: Specifically > 2.5, so 2.6 and above @Dzhaughn.