# How to run Jacoco with Java 7 and spring-instrument?

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, java-7, jacoco

Since I had some problems using cobertura with Java 7 - I'm trying *Jacoco*.
My project has a parent `pom.xml` and sub projects.
In one project I use spring to run some integration tests - so I have this plugin in this project's `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <!-- -XX:-UseSplitVerifier is for java 7 -->
        <argLine>
            -XX:-UseSplitVerifier 
            -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${spring.version}/spring-instrument-${spring.version}.jar
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Since I use Java 7, I've set this plugin in the parent `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
    <optimize>true</optimize>
    <debug>true</debug>
    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
    <encoding>utf8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now, when I'm using `mvn clean install` all the projects have this file in the `/target` folder: `jacoco.exec`
; But this project that uses the `spring-instrument` does not have this file.
I think the problem is that *Jacoco* wishes to use the `asm` of `spring-instrument` but it fails (but I'm not sure I'm right).

The *Jacoco* version is `0.6.3.201306030806`.

Why does *Jacoco* fails to instrument in this case?
How can I overcome this?

I thought maybe I can configure the *maven-compiler-plugin* to compile the code to 1.6 and then I wouldn't need the *maven-surefire-plugin* plugin. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3):

The argLine value defined by Jacoco Maven Plugin is being rewritten by the Surefire Plugin.

Set a property name in your "jacoco-maven-plugin" configuration like this:

```
<propertyName>coverageAgent</propertyName>
```

and then edit the argLine in your surefire plugin configuration so it includes Jacoco's agent:

```
<argLine>
    -XX:-UseSplitVerifier
    ${coverageAgent} 
    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${spring.version}/spring-instrument-${spring.version}.jar
</argLine>
```

Notice that the Jacoco's agent is placed before the Spring's Instrument. That's the way it should be done because Jacoco has problems dealing with modified bytecode (e.g. the one produced by AspectJ LTW).

Actually, even when being the first agent, Jacoco's reports can still be wrong, but the problem is usually limited to a small set of circumstances (e.g. http://sourceforge.net/p/eclemma/discussion/614869/thread/3d875388 ).

Answer (score 2):

my guess is that JaCoCo also uses the java command line, as it is probably implemented as a javaagent.

could it be that the spring-instrument javaagent overrides the JaCoCo one ?

Comment: I think not: `[DEBUG]   (s) argLine = -javaagent:C:\Users\noaml\.m2\repository\org\jacoco\org.jacoco.agent\0.6.3.201306030806\org.jacoco.agent-0.6.3.201306030806-runtime.jar=destfile=...\target\jacoco.exec
`

Comment: then perhaps the other way - the jacoco overrides the java agent of the sprint instrument, and the code doesn't run because of it?

Comment: Thanks for the replay - but that's not likely, in this case the tests wouldn't pass at all...