# Unit tests passing through Maven, but failing through Cobertura: "Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 65"

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, cobertura, spring-mvc-test

I recently added the Cobertura plugin to my Java/Spring-MVC project.  The strange thing is that all my unit tests were passing, and they still pass when Maven does its initial test run, but then when Cobertura tries to run the tests, they all fail with the same error message:

```
Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 65 in method xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx;)V at offset 40
```

I have no idea why this is happening and don't even know how to go about fixing it.  I've searched the internet but haven't found any similar problems.  I use JUnit and spring-test-mvc for testing.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: This seems to be a common problem, with very similar questions posted on SO. I posted the resolution to our problem was resolved with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20001391/1279002

Comment: I met the same problem when using cobertura-maven-plugin version 2.4. It worked for both of JDK_1.7.0_79 and JDK_1.8.0_45 when I upgraded cobertura-maven-plugin to version 2.7.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Of course I find the answer right after asking the question, even though I searched for quite awhile before...

The problem is that Cobertura has trouble working with Java 1.7.  You must add the following line to your pom.xml:

```
<argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
```

That goes in the configuration element.  Here is the entire Cobertura section:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                <formats>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
       </plugin>
```

Now everything works as expected.

Comment: Cobertura 2.6 also fixes this.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed by using new plugin

```
                  <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <formats>
                                <format>xml</format>
                            </formats>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>cobertura</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Comment: YES! I tried the -noverify, tried the -XX:-UseSplitVerifier and had no luck. I'm using java 1.8 and this is what worked for me. spent 4 hours on this! Hope other people with the same issue come across this answer