# PowerMock Static method stubbing doesn't appear to work

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, javahg

I've done a bunch of googling and messing around with my code but in the end I can't seem to figure out why the static mocking isn't working with PowerMock and Mockito.

I am trying to mock the `LogCommand` class' `on()` method in the JavaHg Library https://bitbucket.org/aragost/javahg which takes a javahg `BaseRepository` object as an argument and returns an instance of the `LogCommand` class. I want to have this return a mock log object so I can verify whether it's `execute()` command is called, but Mockito exceptions keep getting thrown.

Here's my code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(LogCommand.class)
public class MyRepositoryTest {

    private BaseRepository mockHgRepo;
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        mockHgRepo = mock(BaseRepository.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LogCommand.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void staticMockTest() throws IOException {
        LogCommand mockLogCommand = mock(LogCommand.class);
        when(LogCommand.on(any(BaseRepository.class))).thenReturn(mockLogCommand); // Problem Line!
        myRepository = new MyRepository(mockHgRepo);
    }
}
```

With this code I get stack trace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

-> at com.mycompany.repository.config.MyRepositoryTest.getNextTagNumberTest(MyRepositoryTest.java:39)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().

    at com.mycompany.myRepository.config.MyRepositoryTest.staticMockTest(MyRepositoryTest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit49MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:116)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit49MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:77)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

If I remove the matchers and use a BaseRepository object in the when instead of a matcher, it still throws an exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
   It is a limitation of the mock engine.

-> at com.mycompany.repository.config.MyRepositoryTest.getNextTagNumberTest(MyRepositoryTest.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit49MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:116)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit49MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:77)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated--thanks!

---

Edit: As per @Ducan's request, here is some example code that is doing a very similar thing as the third party code I am using. Thanks!

```
public class TestRepository {

    private String repoLocation;

    public static TestRepository on (String repoLocation) {
        return new TestRepository(repoLocation);
    }

    public TestRepository(String repoLocation, String extraflags) {
        this.repoLocation = repoLocation;
    }

    private TestRepository (String repoLocation) {
        this(repoLocation, "default flags");
    }
}



@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestRepository.class)
public class MyRepositoryTest {

    @Test
    public void staticMockTest() throws IOException {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(TestRepository.class);
        TestRepository mockRepository = mock(TestRepository.class);
        when(TestRepository.on(anyString())).thenReturn(mockRepository);
    }
}
```

This does not work, but gives a different exception from above, which I'm guessing may be a root problem that are somehow hidden from the ones above:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 51 in method com.mycompany.repository.config.TestRepository.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V at offset 41
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1855)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.setConstructorsAccessible(ClassImposterizer.java:75)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:70)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:110)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:60)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:70)
    at com.mycompany.MyRepositoryTest.staticMockTest(MyRepositoryTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit49MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:116)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit49MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:77)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Progress? If I set it so `on()` calls a constructor that doesn't call another constructor `this()`, it doesn't give me this error.

Comment: Can you simplify your code example so it doesn't rely on external classes we don't have? That would help us experiment to find a solution.

Comment: For last exception "java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames", the solution is to add -XX:-UseSplitVerifier to JVM runtime configuration. See this stackoverflow question for the same : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253173/how-safe-is-it-to-use-xx-usesplitverifier

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had a similar issue trying to test my source code where static method from external class is used.
I solved this using **EasyMock** and **PowerMock**.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@PrepareForTest({ManagementFactory.class, InstallerAppCheckerManagerImpl.class})
public class AppCheckerTester {

  @Test 
  public void testBeanManager() throws Exception {
    // this action is required by PowerMock
    PowerMock.mockStatic(ManagementFactory.class);

    // here is where a mock for static method is defined
    MBeanServer server = PowerMock.createMock(MBeanServer.class);
    EasyMock.expect(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()).andReturn(server);

    // ... 
    PowerMock.replayAll();

    /* some test logic between replay and verify. */

    PowerMock.verifyAll();
  }

}
```

*@PowerMockIgnore* defers the loading of a certain package to the parent classloader. Static method from javax.management is used in this case:

```
ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()
```

*@PrepareForTest* is used to configure both your class and external class.

Hope this ideas help you in your test case.

Comment: Why do you need both - EasyMock and PowerMock

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is in the line:

```
LogCommand mockLogCommand = mock(LogCommand.class);
```

which appears to calling the `mock(Class)` method from the `Mockito` class (due to a static import), when it should be from `PowerMockito`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using PowerMockito.mock() specifically here, and doesn't seem to have fixed it. This LogCommand mock is a regular object mock that I'm trying to get returned from the static on() method which is basically just a static factory method.

Answer (score 0):

Your **PowerMock** setup seems to be incomplete.

1. Include the following three dependencies:

   `testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2'`

   `testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.2'`

   `testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.2'`
2. Add the following rule as a field to your unit test class:

   `@Rule public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();`
3. Additionally add the following annotation to your test class:

   `@PowerMockIgnore("org.mockito.*")`

Then just follow the instructions on [Mocking Static Methods](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#Mocking_Static_Method).

Answer (score 0):

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

do this on your setupMethod to enable anotations

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
```