# Getting this error in eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, cobertura

I am getting this error in eclispe editor all of a sudden It was working previously. I am using Mac OSx [image]

I was not getting that before.  I am building the project using ant which is working fine.  I am using Eclipse 4.3.2.  Is it specific to MAC OS ? I am also cobertura to generate reports.  Also when I run a groovy test case I am getting this

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/HasBeenInstrumented
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2436)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.SpecInfoBuilder.buildFields(SpecInfoBuilder.java:86)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.SpecInfoBuilder.doBuild(SpecInfoBuilder.java:57)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.SpecInfoBuilder.build(SpecInfoBuilder.java:42)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.getSpec(Sputnik.java:78)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.runExtensionsIfNecessary(Sputnik.java:86)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.getDescription(Sputnik.java:55)
    at org.junit.runner.Runner.testCount(Runner.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.countTestCases(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.countTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.HasBeenInstrumented
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 28 more
```

Thanks in advance for your Help.

Comment: What is your Java version?

Comment: And Cobertura version

Comment: java version 1.7.0_65  cobertura-1.9.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Cobertura was pretty much dead project a year ago. Latest Java version it could handle was JDK6. So your problems can be caused by newer version of Java.

There was some development done lately, but my concerns are:

- It is not clear (from [Cobertura current website](https://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/)) with what versions of Java it can cooperate
- [Which is the official Maven bundle](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccobertura)
- How can I get latest version. [Obviously not from github](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/releases).

So we switched to different coverage tool called JaCoCo. It can handle Java7 coverage (not sure about Java8 so far). If you want nice plugin in Eclipse, go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace... -> Type "EclEmma" into Find bar -> Go. This plugin is using JaCoCo under the hood.

**EDIT**

After posting your versions of Java and Cobertura, my suspects become true. Your version of Cobertura works only with Java6. Thy to update Cobertura version somehow, or switch to above suggested alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your insight.  It was working till yesterday and I am not sure whether any java update i got from Mac os is causing this and I am not finding answers on the net

Comment: So it was probably working by accident. If you don't believe me, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151470/cobertura-java-7-support